# Represent Flowchart-specified Algorithms in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm confronted with the task of implementing algorithms (mostly business logic style) expressed as flowcharts. I'm aware that flowcharts are not the best algorithm representation due to its spaghetti-code property (would this be a use-case for CPS?), but I'm stuck with the specification expressed as flowcharts.

Although I could transform the flowcharts into more appropriate equivalent representations before implementing them, that could make it harder to "recognize" the orginal flow-chart in the resulting implementation, so I was hoping there is some way to directly represent flowchart-algorithms as (maybe monadic) EDSLs in Haskell, so that the semblance to the original flowchart-specification would be (more) obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible representation of flowcharts is by using a group of mutually tail-recursive functions, by translating "go to step X" into "evaluate function X with state S". For improved readability, you can combine into a single function both the action (an external function that changes the state) and the chain of `if/else` or pattern matching that helps determine what step to take next.

This is assuming, of course, that your flowcharts are to be hardcoded (as opposed to loaded at runtime from an external source).

Comment: well, I didn't write it in the original question, but that's how I'm doing it now lacking for better ideas (which I can do in any language with tail-recursion support), I was hoping there to be something more Haskell-ish; and yes, they're supposed to be hardcoded

Comment: @hvr, I think this idea is clean and a fairly direct encoding.  You have defined yourself out of a Haskellish solution, because Haskellish programs don't think in terms of control flow.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Arrows](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow) would fit exactly what you describe. Either do a visualization of arrows (should be quite simple) or generate/transform arrow code from flow-graphs if you must.

Comment: I'd be wary of arrows here -- the flowchart is for *control flow* -- arrows capture *data flow*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's "global" state within the flowchart, then that makes sense to package up into a state monad. At least then, unlike how you're doing it now, each call doesn't need any parameters, so can be read as a) modify state, b) conditional on current state, jump.